# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{x}{x^3-1} \, \mathrm{d}x$ by using complex analysis

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, complex-integration

If someone could please explain how to do these kinds of integrals, where the boundaries of integration are not $_{-}^{+}\infty$ and the function is not even, that is how to choose the complex function and the contour?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{x}{x^3-1} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: With $z:=-x^3$ we want $\tfrac13\int_0^\infty\frac{z^{-1/3}dz}{1+z}$. What we need next is a _keyhole contour_. The argument is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2245314/complex-keyhole-contour-integral). You should get $\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: For this problem, make a contour around $e^{2 i \pi / 3}$ by adding in a ray extending from $0$ to the upper right at an angle of $60^\circ$.  The integral along the ray will equal the desired integral, so the answer will be half the residue at $e^{2 i \pi / 3}$.