# Complex Integration $\int^\infty_0\frac{(\ln x)^2}{1+x^2}\,dx$ using theory of Residue and Branch Cut

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

The question asks to compute
$$\displaystyle\int^\infty_0\frac{(\ln x)^2}{1+x^2}\,dx$$
but I have no idea how to do that. I have thought about using the following branch cut but doesn't seem to work.
[image]
[Branch Cut Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziQm7.png)

Comment: That contour won't help unless you convert the integral to one on $(-\infty,\,\infty)$. But a [keyhole contour](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2245314), $\gamma$ say, would be useful. You can compute $A_n:=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^xdx}{1+x^2},\,0\le n\le2$ by expressing $B_n:=\oint_\gamma\frac{\ln zdz}{1+z^2},\,1\le n\le3$ [sic] in terms of them, then evaluating the $B_n$ by the residue theorem.

Comment: (Sorry, $A_n,\,B_n$ should be respectively defined in the above comment as $\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^nxdx}{1+x^2},\,\oint_\gamma\frac{\ln^nzdz}{1+z^2}$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute $y = \ln x$ and get
$$\displaystyle\int^\infty_0\dfrac{(\ln x)^2}{1+x^2}\,dx = \displaystyle\int^\infty_{-\infty}\dfrac{y^2}{1+e^{2y}}e^y\,dy = \frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int^\infty_{-\infty}\dfrac{y^2}{\cosh(y)}\,dy = -\frac{1}{2}g''(0)$$
where $g = \mathscr{F}(\frac{1}{\cosh}) = \pi\operatorname{sech}(\frac{\pi}{2}y)$. So $g''(0) = -\pi(\frac{\pi}{2})^2$, which gives
$$\displaystyle\int^\infty_0\dfrac{(\ln x)^2}{1+x^2}\,dx = -\frac{1}{2}g''(0) = (\frac{\pi}{2})^3 = \frac{\pi^3}{8}$$